# Getting TLE error in Kickstart Alarm challenge, Gooogle KickStart 2019

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, performance

I'm trying to solve the **Kickstart Alarm** problem given in the **Practice Round of the KickStart 2019**.
That can be found at https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/archive/2019
Doing the math transformations, I got a generic expression that calculates the **contribution of each element** at the index "i" of the Parameter Array "A" of length "N" to the final result.

```
[A[i] * (N - i)] * [K + (2^1 + 2^2 + ... + 2^K) + ... + ((i+1)^1 + (i+1)^2 + ... + (i+1)^K)], when i > 0
A[0] * N * K, otherwise
```

I used modular arithmetic over the modulus given by the challenge, 10^9 + 7, trying to optimize the calculations. Below is the solution implemented in Python 3.5 I tried.

```py
def generate_parameter_array(N, x, y, C, D, E1, E2, F):
    array = [(x + y) % F]
    for i in range(N - 1):
        old_x = x
        x = (C * x + D * y + E1) % F
        y = (D * old_x + C * y + E2) % F
        array.append((x + y) % F)
    return array

def solution():
    T = int(input())
    mypow = pow
    for t in range(1, T + 1):
        test_case = [int(n) for n in input().split(" ")]
        N = test_case[0] # Length of the parameter array
        K = test_case[1] # Number of exponential powers
        A = generate_parameter_array(N, *(test_case[2:]))
        result = 0
        mod = 10**9 + 7
        P_sum = K # accumulator of the geometric progressions
        for i in range(1, N):
            P_sum = (P_sum + ((mypow(i+1, K+1, mod) - (i+1)) * (mypow(i,mod-2,mod)))) % mod
            result = (result + (((A[i] * (N - i)) % mod) * P_sum) % mod) % mod
        result = (result + (((A[0] * N) % mod) * K) % mod) % mod
        print('Case #{}: {}'.format(t, result))
```

This solution exceeds the time limit of the challenge at the hidden test set, I'm getting the TLE error. Is there a way to optimize more this algorithm, or am I limited by Python? Please point out my mistakes. Thank you!

Comment: looking at the top solutions it seems that they are all solved using C++

Comment: @chess4ever I think that is a heavy computation for script languages like Python, I searched and saw that many algorithms which requires heavy computation are implemented in Java/C/C++ when people get time limit erros in code challenges..

Comment: Yes exactly, Python is preferred over c++ when working with big numbers arithmetic because there are no overflows and other similar issues. I do prefer using python when possible but sometimes it is required to go for c++